# Getting a unknown modifier error when using a RegEx

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm not very knowledgeable with regular expresions, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

I'm using the following code to match all the emails in the string `$str` and saving them in the array `$match`:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/",
    $str,
    $match
);
```

Apparently there's a problem in the regex (which I got from [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.emailaddress)) because I'm getting this error:

> Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier
>   '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\Framework\Sanitizer.class.php on
>   line 38

Can someone tell me what's the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the forward slash before that equals sign, e.g:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/",
    $str,
    $match
);
```

"/" is the delimiter for the whole expression, so it must be escaped in the regex itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape many of the characters in that string with a backslash.
Some of those you want to escape is: /?^{|} .

I would have written it like this:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/",
    $str,
    $match
);
```

I find this site quite useful when it comes to matching e-mail adresses:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Might want to point exactly WHICH usages of those chars need to be escaped. There's a few places where they're a valid unescaped usage.

Comment: I'm no expert in regular expressions, but I find this a useful site when it comes to regexps for e-mail matching: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html .